# How to delete Documents from a Lucene Index using Term or QueryParser

Tags: lucene, indexing

I am trying to delete documents from Lucene Index. 
I want to delete only the specified file from lucene index .

My following program is deleting the index which can be searched using keyword analyzer but my required filename can be searched only using StandardAnalyzer . So is it any way to set standard analyzer in my  term or instead of term how can i user QueryParser to delete the Documents from lucene index.

```
 try{
    File INDEX_DIR= new File("D:\\merge lucene\\abc\\");

    Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(INDEX_DIR);

     IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory,false);
     Term term= new Term("path","fileindex23005.htm");
    int l=   indexReader.deleteDocuments(term);
                      indexReader.close();

    System.out.println("documents deleted");
  }
  catch(Exception x){x.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you are using Lucene 3.6 or before, otherwise `IndexReader.deleteDocuments` no longer exists.  You should, however, be using IndexWriter instead, anyway.

If you can only find the document using query parser, then just run a normal query, then iterate through the documents returned, and delete them by docnum, along the lines of:

```
Query query = queryParser.parse("My Query!");
ScoreDoc[] docs = searcher.search(query, 100).scoreDocs;
For (ScoreDoc doc : docs) {
    indexReader.deleteDocument(doc.doc);
}
```

Or better yet (simpler, uses non-defunct, non-deprecated functionality), just use an `IndexWriter`, and pass it the query directly:

```
Query query = queryParser.parse("My Query!");
writer.deleteDocuments(query);
```

Comment: Its deleting the old documents but size of the index files does not reduces

Comment: Yes, deletions aren't immediately eliminated from file structure.  They are buffered in memory temporarily (controlled in `IndexWriterConfig`), and then effectively flagged as deleted.  Eventually deletions will be flushed from the index, as specified in your [`MergePolicy`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MergePolicy.html).  Deletion can be an expensive operation, I wouldn't recommend trying to set it up to merge every time a deletion is received, especially if deletion is a fairly common operation.

Comment: @femtoRgon after deleting the document from index files, if i query the index, will it return the deleted records also?

Comment: @Shankar If you delete, then index.Commit(), the deletion is reflected in any new Readers created from said Index - the deleted records will not be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Adding for future reference for someone like me,  where delete documents is on indexWriter , you may use

> indexWriter.deleteDocuments(Term... terms)

instead of using deleteDocuments(query) method; to have less hassle if you have to match only one field. **Be-aware that this method treats terms as OR condition if multiple terms are passed**. So it will match any term and will delete all records. The code below will match state=Tx in documents stored and will delete matching records.

```
  indexWriter.deleteDocuments(
        new Term("STATE", "Tx")
      );
```

For combining different fields with AND condition, we may use following code:

```
 BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();

//note year is stored as int , not as string when document is craeted.
//if you use Term here which will need 2016 as String, that will not match with documents stored with year as int.
 Query yearQuery = IntPoint.newExactQuery("year", 2016);
 Query stateQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("STATE", "TX"));
 Query cityQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("CITY", "CITY NAME"));

 builder.add(yearQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
 builder.add(stateQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
 builder.add(cityQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

 indexWriter.deleteDocuments(builder.build());
```

Comment: I am adding a unique field as `doc.add(new TextField("uid", product.getUid(), Field.Store.YES));` but when I try to delete the document as `Term term = new Term("uid", uniqueId); getIndexWriter().deleteDocuments(term);` throws a NPE I have tried both `TextField` and `StringField` and the all give an NPE. Where am I going wrong please. Using Lucene 5.4

Answer (score 0):

As @dillippattnaik pointed out, multiple terms result in **OR**. I have updated his code to make it **AND** using BooleanQuery:

```
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery
{
   { new TermQuery( new Term( "year", "2016" ) ), Occur.MUST },
   { new TermQuery( new Term( "STATE", "TX" ) ), Occur.MUST },
   { new TermQuery( new Term( "CITY", "CITY NAME" ) ), Occur.MUST }
};

indexWriter.DeleteDocuments( query );
```